# Javascript ScrollTop Function help

Tags: javascript

i got the function below which popups up a window but fails to scroll the main page to the appropiate div height.

```
function open_window(getDiv) 
{
var objDiv = document.getElementById(getDiv);
document.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
new_window = open("http://www.mysite.com/","MySite","width=610,height=510,left=600,top=400");
new_window.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding this right (You want to scroll the page to wherever the div is on the page), then you are using the wrong property from `objDiv`.

`scrollHeight` is used to figure out what the height of the contents inside of the container is. The property you are looking for is `offsetTop`. Here is an updated version of your code:

```
function open_window(getDiv) 
{
var objDiv = document.getElementById(getDiv);
document.scrollTop = objDiv.offsetTop;
new_window = open("http://www.mysite.com/","MySite","width=610,height=510,left=600,top=400");
new_window.focus();
}
```